# MongoDb Asp.Core define and use key (not value) in a relationship

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

### Context

In our app, we permit to our users to upload files, which will be placed in a queue for review and approbation.

User's file ID will be stored as a "sub-list" (I don't know the name) in the user specific Mongo Database.

### Question summary

My question is all about defining a file Object ID as a key in my user database and the getting this user's uploaded file ID to retrieve the current file `state` value.

### Our model

```
public class User
{
    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool hasAcceptedTerms { get; set; } = false;
    public IList<UserFile> SubmittedFiles { get; set; }
}
public class UserFile
{
    public string fileID { get; set; } // Correspond to the Object Id of a file
    public bool hasFile { get; set; }
}
public class File
{
    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string fileServerIdentifier { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string filename { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string user { get; set; } = string.Empty; //Corresponds to the user object Id
    public int state { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

### Mongo JSON database example

```
{
  "files" : {
    "5349b4ddd2781d08c09890f3" : {
      "fileServerIdentifier" : "7e1fed29-c3b2-4d7e-9e00-bbff38aecb51",
      "filename" : "document.pdf",
      "user" : "507f1f77bcf86cd799439011",
      "state": 0
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "507f1f77bcf86cd799439011" : {
      "email" : "username@domain.com",
      "hasAcceptedTerms" : true,
      "submitted-files" : {
        "5349b4ddd2781d08c09890f3" : true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### My question

1. First of all, is my link between User and File correct: I mean the `public IList<UserFile> SubmittedFiles { get; set; }`?
2. How can I add, in an existing `users` collection (user filtered by Id), a fileID **as a key** with value `true`.
3. And as a matter of consequence how to retrieve recursively all the `fileID` which are keys and not values so I can use them to retrieve recursively the corresponding `state` in `File` database?

Comment: Hi .. first of all i think your fileID property in the UserFile is not correct .. i think it has to be a String (or Guid) .. but better String

Comment: Corrected thanks :) typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your JSON is defenetly wrong. From example, how could look single user in "users" collection, take attention, `SubmittedFiles` is an array:

```
{
   "_id":"5349b4ddd2781d08c09890f3",
   "email":"email@email.com",
   "hasAcceptedTerms":true,
   "SubmittedFiles":[
      {
         "fileID":"5349b4ddd2781d08c09890f3",
         "hasFile":true
      }
   ]
}
```

2) It's possible to change just this one value of the array on server, but i am not sure, that i could write this mongo query. I suggest to get `User` from collection, change value and write user back:

```
var userLoaded = collection.Find(x=>x.Id =="586f92559afc29759076efd8").Single();
userLoaded.SubmittedFiles.First(x=>x.fileID=="5349b4ddd2781d08c09890f3").hasFile = true;
collection.ReplaceOne(u=>u.Id==userLoaded.Id,  userLoaded);
```

3) If you want get all fileIds, you could for example use this query:

```
collection.Find(x=>true)
           .Project(t=>t.SubmittedFiles.Select(f=>f.fileID))
           .ToEnumerable()
           .SelectMany(s=>s)
```

Comment: Thanks! With this method and new JSON format, do I have to change my models?

Comment: The code i have wrotten is based on model you provided, not on json. And json is just stored in mongo, you don't write o read it on your own. I think you shouldn't change anything, just add this funcionality.